# Apache Conf - FilesMatch allow only in current folder, not subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

is it possible to allow access to a specific file via <files> or <filesmatch> so that this rule is not applied to identically named files in subfolders?

Current setup:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/>
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Direcotry>

<Directory /var/www/admin/>
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Direcotry>
```

Let's assume the following:

1. We have one index.php in web-root, one in subfolder admin, and in various other subfolders, there are also some index.php files.
2. No *.php should be accessible, if not explicitely allowed - in this case only /index.php and /admin/index.php

**What happens:**

When allowing access to the webroots index.php, all index.php files in all subfolders become accessible.

**What was tried:**

Using DirectoryMatch to disallow access to index.php in subfolders.

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/>
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Direcotry>

<DirectoryMatch "/var/www/(.+)/">
    <Files index.php>
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>

<Directory /var/www/admin/>
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Direcotry>
```

Now, access to all index.php Files in all subfolders is disallowed - but also to the index.php in /admin/ which still should be allowed.

**Also tried with absolut pathes to the files**

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<Files /var/www/index.php>
    Allow from all
</Files>
<Files /var/www/admin/index.php>
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

This also did not work.
No index.php file was accessible - even the ones in the webroot and the admin-folder were not accessible.

I believe that there are better approaches to solve a problem like this?

Kind regards,

Dominik

Comment: There is something wrong with your setups: you cannot close an opened `<Files>` tag with a `</FilesMatch>` tag. Take a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch That certainly should be pointed out in your http servers error log file. You need to monitor that file when you make changes to your setup.

Comment: Hello arkascha,

thank you for your hint.
Unfortunatly this mistake does not exist in the real config file. This mistake came up while writing the question here. Even with the correct open and closing tags, this problem occurs

Comment: IIRC, then you can place a `<FilesMatch>` directive inside a `<Directory>` tag. And you can define another directory tag using a wildcard for the subfolders (so `<Directory /some/path/*>`) and use an access denying `<FilesMatch>` directive in there again. Might be worth giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to arkascha,

The DirectoryMatch method was the wrong idea.

The solution for this is simple - as recommended by arkascha:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/>
    <Files index.php">
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/*/*">
    <Files index.php>
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/admin/>
    <Files index.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Thank you very much.